# Why does the “round” function not work while concatenating strings?

Tags: dolphindb

Why does the “round” function not work while concatenating strings?

```py
newValue = 126708.8285
uatField = regexReplace("M1_dtt","dtt", "uat")
newCondition = " and (" + uatField + " = " + round(newValue, 4) +" )"
```

The result is as below:

```py
and (M1_uat = 126708.828500000003259 )
```

Why doesn’t the function “round” work?

Answer (score 0):

The [format](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/f/format.html) can work, scripts is as follows:

```py
newCondition = "and (" + uatField +" = "+ format(newValue,"0.0000") +" )"
```

result:

```py
and (M1_uat = 126708.8285 )
```